# How to Search Updates for Applications from Local Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, updates

I've made a *Console Application* in *C#* Program using Visual Studio and published it successfully on a folder at my desktop. But I can't make Visual Studio to set a local folder for searching updates, it says I must type a "fully qualified URL", but I don't have a Deployment Server (also I don't want to use one for now).

Am I missing something? What should I do?

Comment: So you basically want to give everyone using your application access to your computer to get updates?

Comment: @DavidStockinger No, I just want to test it out on a local folder

Comment: Then how do you expect this to work?

Comment: When I used the Publish Wizard, it said I could use a folder in my computer. Anyway, I've set an FTP server for it, if it isn't possible, it shouldn't hand me the option to use a folder